# Custom rolling window nested resampling with mlr3

Tags: r, mlr3

Since last version, `mlr3tuning` package supports (custom) instantiated resampling in `AutoTuner` class: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3tuning/releases/tag/v0.17.2

I have tried to construct rolling window CV's with custom resmapling as in the following link https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-nested-cross-validation-76adba623eb9 (figure 1).

I want to tune hyperparameters on (let's say )row ids 1:1000 (for example 1:800 train and 801:100 test). and then I would like to evaluate the model on test set, say 1001:1100.

Her is my try:

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3tuning)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3learners)


# task
task  = tsk("iris")
task_ = task$clone()
data_ = task_$data()
data_ = cbind(data_, monthid = c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 30), rep(3, 30), rep(4, 30), rep(5, 30)))
task = as_task_classif(data_, target = "Species")

# inner custom rolling window resampling
custom = rsmp("custom")
task_ <- task$clone()
task_$set_col_roles("monthid", "group")
groups = task_$groups
rm(task_)
groups_v <- groups[, unique(group)]
train_length <- 2
test_length <- 1
train_groups <- lapply(0:(length(groups_v)-(train_length+1)), function(x) x + (1:train_length))
test_groups <- lapply(train_groups, function(x) tail(x, 1) + test_length)
train_sets <- lapply(train_groups, function(x) groups[group %in% groups_v[x], row_id])
test_sets <- lapply(test_groups, function(x) groups[group %in% groups_v[x], row_id])
custom$instantiate(task, train_sets, test_sets)

# outer custom rolling window resampling
customo = rsmp("custom")
task_ <- task$clone()
task_$set_col_roles("monthid", "group")
groups = task_$groups
rm(task_)
groups_v <- groups[, unique(group)]
train_length_out <- train_length + test_length
test_length_out <- 1
train_groups_out <- lapply(0:(length(groups_v)-(train_length_out+1)), function(x) x + (1:train_length_out))
test_groups_out <- lapply(train_groups_out, function(x) tail(x, 1) + test_length_out)
train_sets_out <- lapply(train_groups_out, function(x) groups[group %in% groups_v[x], row_id])
test_sets_out <- lapply(test_groups_out, function(x) groups[group %in% groups_v[x], row_id])
customo$instantiate(task, train_sets_out, test_sets_out)

# inspect custom cv's
custom$train_set(1)
custom$test_set(1)
(max(custom$train_set(1)) + 1) == head(custom$test_set(1), 1) # test set starts after train set
customo$train_set(1)
customo$test_set(1)
(max(customo$train_set(1)) + 1) == head(customo$test_set(1), 1) # test set starts after train set
all(c(custom$train_set(1), custom$test_set(1)) %in% customo$train_set(1)) # first outer set contains all inner sets
length(intersect(customo$test_set(1), c(custom$train_set(1), custom$test_set(1)))) == 0

# costruct graph
graph = po("removeconstants", id = "removeconstants_1", ratio = 0)  %>>%
  po("branch", options = c("nop_prep", "yeojohnson", "pca", "ica"), id = "prep_branch") %>>%
  gunion(list(po("nop", id = "nop_prep"), po("yeojohnson"), po("pca", scale. = TRUE), po("ica"))) %>>%
  po("unbranch", id = "prep_unbranch") %>>%
  po("learner", learner = lrn("classif.rpart"))
plot(graph)
graph_learner = as_learner(graph)
as.data.table(graph_learner$param_set)[1:70, .(id, class, lower, upper)]
search_space = ps(
  prep_branch.selection = p_fct(levels = c("nop_prep", "yeojohnson", "pca", "ica")),
  pca.rank. = p_int(2, 6, depends = prep_branch.selection == "pca"),
  ica.n.comp = p_int(2, 6, depends = prep_branch.selection == "ica"),
  yeojohnson.standardize = p_lgl(depends = prep_branch.selection == "yeojohnson")
)
at = auto_tuner(
  method = "random_search",
  learner = graph_learner,
  resampling = custom,
  measure = msr("classif.acc"),
  search_space = search_space
)

# resmpling
rr = resample(task, at, customo, store_models = TRUE)
```

I get an error:

```
INFO  [09:46:49.340] [mlr3] Applying learner 'removeconstants_1.prep_branch.nop_prep.yeojohnson.pca.ica.prep_unbranch.classif.rpart.tuned' on task 'data_' (iter 1/2)
INFO  [09:46:49.362] [mlr3] Applying learner 'removeconstants_1.prep_branch.nop_prep.yeojohnson.pca.ica.prep_unbranch.classif.rpart.tuned' on task 'data_' (iter 2/2)
Error: Train set 3 of inner resampling 'custom' contains row ids not present in task 'data_': {91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first outer training set contains these ids:

```r
train_sets_out
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

This means row 1 to 90 are available in the inner resampling.

The third training set of the inner resampling needs rows 61 to 120 but rows 91 to 120 are not available.

```r
train_sets
#> [[3]]
#>  [1]  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120
```

So that can't work. Check out figure 4.7 in the [book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/optimization.html#sec-nested-resampling) to see how the outer and inner resampling work together.

Comment: I am awae of that problem but I thouth there is better way to define CV-s. It would probabbly work if I set fist outer set in a way thay all other months are test ste, but that would not replicate figure 1 from the link.
Maybe, the better approach would be to first tune hyperparameters by resampling and than mannually construct additional test sets for model evaluations.